# How to use ChoiceChip wiget with categories without hard coding

Tags: flutter, dart

i'm new in flutter and i want to make an interface like this image below

[image]

For that I need to use Choice Chip widgets

Here is my code that builds a set of ChoiceChips:

```
 String _selectedIndex;

List<String> _options = [
'Bueiro entupido',
'Bueiro sem tampa',
'Esgoto a céu aberto',
"Ponto de alagamento",
'Vazamento de água',
'Falta de água'
```

];

```
_buildChoiceList() {
List<Widget> choices = List();
_options.forEach((item) {
  choices.add(Container(
    child: ChoiceChip(
      label: Text(item),
      labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
      selectedColor: Colors.pinkAccent,
      backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
      selected: _selectedIndex == item,
      onSelected: (selected) {
        setState(() {
          _selectedIndex = item;
        });
      },
    ),
  ));
});
return choices;
```

}

But the `_options` list needs to be larger with different types of categories, that is, a list with sublists.

I've tried several ways(with a list with subcategories), but I can't reproduce the layout of the image above.

I can only think of a solution, only if I do hard coding, creating 1 `_buildChoiceList` () for each separate list that I have.

What is the best solution for this? so that when I need to create a new category, I don't need to create a new `_buildChoiceList()` and another List.

Thank you for your attention :)